# Combining 2 .groupby() Bar Plots

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I was given a Final Project assignment for my Data Analyzation with Python Certification.
Since I'm very new to this, I've been wondering how I combine 2 .groupby() bar plots made using .plot.barh() like these:

```
day_df.groupby(by = ["yr", "season", "weathersit"]).agg({"cnt" : "sum"}).plot.barh()
```

and

```
day_df.groupby(by = ["yr", "season", "weathersit"]).agg({"cnt" : "mean"}).plot.barh()
```

Tried this one and it doesn't work:

```
#Defining Variables
day_mean_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(day_df.groupby(by = ["yr", "season", "weathersit"]).agg({"cnt" : "mean"}))
day_sum_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(day_df.groupby(by = ["yr", "season", "weathersit"]).agg({"cnt" : "sum"}))

r1 = np.arange(6)
width1 = 0.5
 
# Creating the subplot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.bar(r1, day_mean_dataframe["yr", "season", "weathersit"], width = width1)
plt.bar(r1 + width1, day_sum_dataframe["yr", "season", "weathersit"], width = width1)
 
 
# Displaying the plot
plt.show()
```

I've tried a lot of codes and they're not working which leads me here.
Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi welcome ) how about merge and then plot the merged dataframe ?

```
day_mean_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(day_df.groupby(by=["yr", "season", "weathersit"]).agg({"cnt": "mean"})).reset_index()
day_sum_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(day_df.groupby(by=["yr", "season", "weathersit"]).agg({"cnt": "sum"})).reset_index()

# merging the dataframes
merged_df = pd.merge(day_mean_dataframe, day_sum_dataframe, on=["yr", "season", "weathersit"], suffixes=('_mean', '_sum'))

# creating the subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
r1 = np.arange(len(merged_df))
width1 = 0.4 

# plotting the bars
ax.bar(r1, merged_df["cnt_mean"], width=width1, label='Mean')
ax.bar(r1 + width1, merged_df["cnt_sum"], width=width1, label='Sum')

# add labels
ax.set_xticks(r1 + width1 / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{row.yr}, {row.season}, {row.weathersit}' for _, row in merged_df.iterrows()], rotation=90)
ax.legend()


# plotting the horizontal bars
bars_mean = ax.barh(r1, merged_df["cnt_mean"], height=width1, label='Mean')
bars_sum = ax.barh(r1 + width1, merged_df["cnt_sum"], height=width1, label='Sum')
ax.set_yticks(r1 + width1 / 2)
ax.set_yticklabels([f'{row.yr}, {row.season}, {row.weathersit}' for _, row in merged_df.iterrows()])
ax.legend()
```

Comment: oh wow this is a good idea, thanks a lot! if i want to make it horizontal, what do i change?

Comment: @Connor857 updated with horizontal bar plots

Comment: got it, thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: np, happy to help )

Comment: hey, another quick question: I just modified the plots to have 2 x axises because the gap numbers between mean and sum are quite big which results in the mean plot isn't showing. Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: can you post your code or the error you are getting ?

Comment: Oh it's alright, I've figured it out. Thank you for reaching back :)